# How can I use keyboard shortcuts to open a PDF externally in firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't want to turn off the internal preview, but sometimes need to switch to an external program for 2-up fullscreen view. To do that I have to click the down-arrow download symbol. How would I do that just using keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a built-in way, but it's doable with a userscript or extension. Of course, this makes certain assumptions that an updated pdf.js could break.

GreaseMonkey script example that binds download to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 245012
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

if (unsafeWindow.PDFJS && document.querySelector('base').href === 'resource://pdf.js/web/') {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev) {
        if (ev.ctrlKey && ev.key == '.') {
            document.getElementById('download').click();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! And if it breaks in the future, it should be easy enough to figure out how to fix it with the developer tools.